# Adding UIPinchGestureRecognizer on a UIScrollview's subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I'm adding a view as a `UIScrollview`'s subview. This subview determines the `contentsize` of `scrollview`. On this view I add a UIPinchGesture and in selector target method of gesture i resize the view and reset contentsize of scrollview. BTW I earlier tried zooming of scrollview but it didn't fulfilled my requirement so I did it with `UIPinchGesture`. My problem is that normally the content size of scrollview is greater than it's frame so scrolling is enabled. When I try to pinch with two fingers the scrollview's scrolling is triggered and Pinchgesture seldomly recognized. I can't disable scrolling of `UIScrollview` as this is one of my requirement. Can anybody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't get it. UIScrollView has delaysContentTouches property but it is YES by default.

Comment: I wrote the wrong comment earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `delayContentTouches` property of `UIScrollView` to `NO` (instead of the default `YES`). This will allow the touch to propagate to the subviews of the scroll view immediately.